# What does "TON" indicate on cricket bat?

Tags: cricket, equipment, terminology

I have seen "TON" written on lots of cricket bats like these*: (click to zoom)

[image] [image]

What does it actually indicate? Is it a brand name? Or a symbol of approved bat by ICC? Or it indicates that a cricketer hit a ton (century) with this bat?

---

<sup>* Picture taken from https://www.espncricinfo.com/</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"TON" is a brand name of cricket bat manufactured by [Sareen Sports Industries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sareen_Sports_Industries) (also known as SS Cricket), an Indian cricket supply company.

Answer (score 4):

The "TON" stamp on the edge of a cricket bat is the branded logo of SAREEN SPORTS (SS) also known as Sunridges. They brand the edges to ensure that when their bats are used by professional cricketers with other sponsor's labels, the origin of the bat remains. This is a very common practice in India where SAREEN are based. The "TON" stamp also is only applied to English willow bats and "SS" is stamped on Kashmir willow bats.